# Java 8 Lambda Expression Junit Test

Tags: java, junit, java-8

I have this piece of code I need to test

```
  Optional.ofNullable(someObject.getIssue())
            .map(issue -> eventMap.getOrDefault(issue, DEFAULT_VAL))
            .ifPresent(event -> {do something;});
```

I want to test what event is returned from the eventMap. 
How do I test this in my unit test? Is there a way to capture the value of the "event" passed in the "ifPresent" ?

Comment: You could just write a test for `eventMap.getOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the code that you have in `do something;`. If you call function of some object and passing `event` as an parameter, you can mock your object with e.g Mockito and check if incoming  parameter is null or not.

Another way is to spy (again e.g Mockito) for `eventMap` when `.getOrDefault` called with specific `issue` object. (assuming that `.ifPresent` method is true method that is itself tested)

Comment: Some useful links:
http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy, http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-methods

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the .ifPresent method there is some complex code and not possible to capture the event value there. Which is why I was wondering if I can capture it when we pass it in .ifPresent()

Answer (score 0):

> I want to test what event is returned from the eventMap

If you are only interested in `event` value, then you can try something like in your test

```
String issue = someObject.getIssue()
// if needed check issue for nullability
String event = eventMap.getOrDefault(issue, DEFAULT_VAL);

// depending upon your test case
assertThat(event).is("YOUR_EXPECTED_VALUE")
```

Comment: And when `eventMap` is inevitably encapsulated inside some class...?

Comment: Only if OP is OK with `getEventMap` method ;) (again not sure if `eventMap` is local var)

Comment: @SagarRohankar  Yeah I can do it this way but I was curious to see if we can capture values from lambda expression itself.